# SQL Server: Performance cost to putting views in another schema

Tags: sql-server, view

We have a normalized database of survey respondents and answers, but, for a variety of reasons, we want to provide denormalized views for our surveys.

It is annoying, however, when doing DB schema stuff, to have to wade through the large list of views, one per survey type and period.

even naming them so they are grouped together makes just a big list of stuff I don't want to see.

(Unfortunately, while each period has the same core variables, the customized questions during the periods have become so large, they won't fit in one view.)

That can partially be alleviated if we put the views in another schema.

The data would still be in the `dbo` schema, but we could put the generated views in a separate schema.

My question is, is there a performance cost to putting views in one schema that are entirely driven by data from tables another schema?

There are no triggers on these views or anything intended other than read-only access. In theory, the only cost difference is that you have to get the view definitions from another schema, but (1) that might already be more costly than I expect, or (2) I'm missing some other cost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is, is there a performance cost to putting views in one schema that are entirely driven by data from tables another schema?

No, not that I'm aware of in SQL Server.

Schemas are just another layer of separation from a naming convention and security perspective, and should not have any direct influence on the execution plan that is generated to execute the query, in regards to performance.

---

One minute thing to be aware of per David Browne:

> If the schemas have different owners then permissions will be checked for the view and for each table referenced by the view. With the tables in the view's schema, permissions will only be checked on the view.

Comment: If the schemas have different owners then permissions will be checked for the view _and_ for each table referenced by the view.  With the tables in the view's schema, permissions will only be checked on the view.

Answer (score 3):

No there is not.

It actually might have a very slight performance **benefit**, if only due to the fact that it forces you to schema-qualify everything.

This means that you are not relying on default schema resolution, which can have a very slight performance impact.

See also [Omiting schema names to manage access to SQL Server databases more flexibly](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/241280/omiting-schema-names-to-manage-access-to-sql-server-databases-more-flexibly)